# Conceptual question on mutual information and entropy

Tags: self-study, references, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

What does mutual information (MI) convey? Looking for good reference books on information theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking a lot of questions on Information Theory. Please can I just recommend some books I've found very helpful rather than try to regurgitate what they say:

(in order of historical importance)

1. "Concepts in Statistical Mechanics" - Arthur Hobson
2. "The Mathematical Theory of Communication" - Claude E. Shannon & Warren Weaver
3. "The Uncertain Reasoner's Companion" - J. B. Paris
4. "Elements of Information Theory" - Thomas M. Cover & Joy A. Thomas
5. "Information Theory" - Robert B. Ash